# Include php in javascript

Tags: php, mysql

I have a photo application, where when a photo is selected, a popout javascript window opens.

Now i have written a PHP/Mysql comment box, which i would like to include in the javascript script. Have you any idea how i could do this?

Comment: There are a whole stack of questions here already that might answer this. Did you try searching before you asked? Or even reading the related questions that displayed when you typed in the question? Or the ones that are shown on the right hand panel on this page?

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching this the wrong way.

Here's the workflow that should happen:

1. User clicks photo.
2. JavaScript sends an AJAX request to the server (asking for a specific file, which will process this request), requesting any data it needs for the popup window.
3. Server (namely `process.php` file) receives this request, queries the MySQL database, and returns (`echo`es) data back to the client.
4. The server's response is caught by JavaScript as the AJAX request's result.
5. JavaScript process this result, in order to produce the correct popup window.

PHP and MySQL work on a different level (the server) than JavaScript (the client). Hence, they cannot operate together. JavaScript can **call** a page on the server (using AJAX) and get the results of that. That is the principle you should be relying on.

Answer (score 1):

You can either load the php generated html based comment thing using an ajax request or you can include it in a javascript dynamically generated.